# How to Find the null space and range of the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the null space and range of the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ on the plane $x+y-z = 0$ What are its nullity and rank?

So my first idea was to find 3 vectors that span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with one of them being the normal vector.

Points on plane: $P(1,1,2),Q(1,-1,0),R(4,-4,0)$

$\vec{n} = \langle1,1,-1\rangle$

$\vec{PQ} = \langle0,-2,-2\rangle$

$\vec{PR} = \langle3,-5,-2\rangle$

Put the vectors into a matrix and reduce...

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&3\\1&-2&-5\\-1&-2&-2 \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow RREF(A)= I $$

This implies that the rank is equal to $3$ and the nullity is $0$. I'm not sure whether or not I'm heading in the right direction with this one. Any pointers would be vastly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The plane $P$ is defined as the set of all $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$
          (1,1,-1)\cdot(x,y,z) = 0.
$$
The range space of the projection consists of all vectors that are orthogonal to the normal $(1,1,-1)$. Therefore the projection has rank 2. The nullity is 1 because the kernel is every scalar multiple of the normal vector.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$A\cdot\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0& 1\\
 0& 1& 1\\
-1&-1&-1
\end{bmatrix}}_X=
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0& 0\\
 0& 1& 0\\
-1&-1& 0
\end{bmatrix}}_Y,$$
(left-multiplying by) $A$ sends the first two columns of $X$ to themselves (because they are in the plane) and the third column to zero (because it's normal to the plane). It thus has rank $2$ and nullity $1$. The range is spanned by the first two vectors, and is the plane (of dimension two), while the null space is spanned by the normal line (of dimension one) through the origin to the plane. Also, the matrix of the transformation could be obtained by multiplying both sides on the right by the inverse of the left hand matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0& 0\\
 0& 1& 0\\
-1&-1& 0
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0& 1\\
 0& 1& 1\\
-1&-1&-1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=YX^{-1}
$$
or by row reducing $[X^t|Y^t]$ to $[I|A^t]$:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1 & 0 &-1 & 1 & 0 &-1\\
0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 1 &-1\\
1 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 &-1 &-1 & 2\\
\end{array}
\right]$$
so that
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0&-1&-1\\
-1& 0&-1\\
 1& 1& 2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$